# How to pass a url parameter(url which auto downloads a pdf on opening in browser) in a flask route

Tags: python-3.x, flask, routes, http-status-code-404, werkzeug

I am currently hardcoding my pdf download url in my code and so when I enter "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" in my browser, the pdf downloads to the specified directory. But when I want to make this dynamic so that I can enter any url after "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" and it should save to my specified directory, that doesnot work and throws up a 404 error.

Sample code when I try to make the route dynamic so as it can process any download link. This throws the 404 error:

```
import urllib
import requests
import ectd
from ectd import convert
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)  

#@app.route("/")
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def download_file(download_url):
    #download_url="https://ptenantectdtest.blob.core.windows.net/documentcontainer/0bbc072c-9114-4ff5-9bc7-dbcc86bff54d?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=bh8gCr6cZIxr2C%2FwB6pB6u%2BxpZFVWZ6S3GWw0QZCqyo%3D&st=2019-07-22T06%3A28%3A56Z&se=2019-07-23T06%3A38%3A56Z&sp=r&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%20%225ca21af9-5b67-45f8-969c-ae571431c665.pdf%22"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open('D:/xyz_.pdf', 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()


    return 'ABC'


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

Sample code when I hardcode the path which works and saves the file in the specified directory:

```
    @app.route("/")
    def download_file():
        download_url="https://ptenantectdtest.blob.core.windows.net/documentcontainer/0bbc072c-9114-4ff5-9bc7-dbcc86bff54d?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=bh8gCr6cZIxr2C%2FwB6pB6u%2BxpZFVWZ6S3GWw0QZCqyo%3D&st=2019-07-22T06%3A28%3A56Z&se=2019-07-23T06%3A38%3A56Z&sp=r&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%20%225ca21af9-5b67-45f8-969c-ae571431c665.pdf%22"
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url)
        file = open('D:/xyz_.pdf', 'wb')
        file.write(response.read())
        file.close()


        return 'ABC'
if __name__ == '__main__':
         app.run()
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the issue when I try to make my route dynamic and not hardcode the pdfdownload link

Comment: not sure if it's your problem, but shouldn't your it be
`@app.route('/<download_url>')
def download_file(download_url)` ?

Comment: And then I will be entering something like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/https://ptenantectdtest.blob.core.windows.net/documentcontainer/831b72ed-b17d-486d-b269-93d77f0d512c?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=tufYjQSPanNvR2lYC9SyzdboiWBvYrUIoVQ0By0bqY8%3D&st=2019-07-22T06%3A28%3A10Z&se=2019-07-23T06%3A38%3A10Z&sp=r&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%20%228d4508bf-453e-45fd-8457-8fd158152ba7.pdf%22` in my browser?

Comment: If I do it, I get a 404 error

Comment: ```@app.route('/<path:path>')
def download_file(download_url):
    #download_url="https://ptenantectdtest.blob.core.windows.net/documentcontainer/0bbc072c-9114-4ff5-9bc7-dbcc86bff54d?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=bh8gCr6cZIxr2C%2FwB6pB6u%2BxpZFVWZ6S3GWw0QZCqyo%3D&st=2019-07-22T06%3A28%3A56Z&se=2019-07-23T06%3A38%3A56Z&sp=r&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%20%225ca21af9-5b67-45f8-969c-ae571431c665.pdf%22"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open('D:/xyz_.pdf', 'wb')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problem in this code:

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def download_file(download_url):
    #download_url="https://ptenantectdtest.blob.core.windows.net/documentcontainer/0bbc072c-9114-4ff5-9bc7-dbcc86bff54d?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=bh8gCr6cZIxr2C%2FwB6pB6u%2BxpZFVWZ6S3GWw0QZCqyo%3D&st=2019-07-22T06%3A28%3A56Z&se=2019-07-23T06%3A38%3A56Z&sp=r&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%20%225ca21af9-5b67-45f8-969c-ae571431c665.pdf%22"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url)
```

If I'm not wrong, you need to use same variable name in route and functions, such as:

```
@app.route('/<path:url_path>')
def download_file(url_path):
```

And then you can do:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_path)
```

Not sure (just haven't seen using another var name in route and in function) , not tested, let me know if it helped!

If it doesn't help, maybe do some debugging to see where the problem occurs in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar and it worked. I replaced download_url with "path" in my code. Can you please help me with one more thing. How can I accept a scanned pdf(which needs to be OCR'd) in the same way from the url and write to a file. Will the existing code work in that scenario?

Comment: you mean pdf is publicly accessible from URL and you just get it? I thought that's what your code does now. however, I don't have experience with handling files this way, only used form upload to get files myself.
also, as you found my answer useful, I will greatly appreciate an upvote.